# Why was the question ‘"Ask forgiveness not permission" - explain’ closed as non-constructive?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

Why was the question ["Ask forgiveness not permission" - explain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265451/ask-forgiveness-not-permission-explain) closed as non-constructive?

> As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, visit the help center for guidance.

The question is asking about a common piece of programming advice, and it presents a particular situation and asks how that advice applies to this situation. I would fully expect answers to involve programming expertise, and indeed the answers (one of which is mine) do so.

So, well, I know I'm often at odds with a large fraction of the SO close voters, but I really don't see what's wrong with this particular question. Sure, it's not SO's favorite debug-my-program, but it even does come with a working code snippet.

Why was this question closed? Should it be closed?

Comment: Voted for reopening. I think that the people who voted for closing either read only the title of the question or thought the question was too open, which would grant a closure as being "too broad" these days.

Comment: @Renan It *is* too broad. The OP is asks "Why would it be *better* for me to..." How? Easier to maintain? Shorter? Faster? Clearer? More responsive? (which is not the same as "faster".) It is also about what is "pythonic" which I cannot see as being anything other than opinion-based. (The OP even gave an opinion about that.) The answers are opinion even if they don't declare themselves as such (except the accepted one which says " IMO it's not crystal clear that ...". I've got substantial replies  to all of them but this is not a discussion forum, hence why we close opinion-based questions.

Comment: @Louis “Better” is obviously primarily “easier to maintain” in this context: performance isn't raised, but “clean, simple and intuitive” is mentioned. Pythonicity isn't the central concern — I don't know what this means (Python is just one tool in my toolbox, I don't venerate the language) and I could still understand the question and answer it. This question can and has beeen answered without needing extended discussion and opinions (such as they are) are backed up by facts. You would not need to reply to the existing answers to present a different point of view, but to write your own answer.

Comment: @Gilles - Thanks for your reply, I feel like there are many of these questions out there!